# Transformers doubt

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, nlp, transformer, attention-mechanism

[image: Transformers encoder layer]

Basically here the $Q$,$K$ and $V$ are passed through a linear layer to obtain the actual $Q$,$K$ and $V$ for self attention mechanism and then we concatenate all of it.

My doubt is, I thought the $Q$,$K$ and $V$ were obtained through the input embedding $X$.

$$Q=XW_q$$
$$K=XW_k$$
$$V=XW_v$$

How come we are using the $Q$,$K$ and $V$ and linearly projecting them to again get back $Q$,$K$ and $V$.

Sorry if my doubt is stupid!

Answer (score 2):

We should not mistake the K, Q and V vectors received by the multi-head attention block with those received by the scaled dot-product block.

The K, Q and V vectors that are fed to the multi-head attention block are projected separately to a lower dimensional space for each of the attention heads so that each scaled-dot product can compute a different result. The dimension of the lower space is the original one divided by the number of heads.

After the scaled dot-product, the results of the individual scaled dot-products are combined back into a single vector, recovering the original dimensionality.

Only in the first attention layer, the values of the vectors fed to the multi-head attention block come from the embeddings. From the second layer on, the inputs come from the outputs of the previous layer.

Comment: So, are you saying that in a Mukti-head attention, Each attention head will receive Q K and V thats linearly projected down so that when computing the scaled dot product, The resulting sum will be different ? If so, All this while what I assumed was, for the first attention layer, We multiply the input X with Wq,Wv,Wk to obtain the first set of Q,K and V and for different heads within the same layer, We multiply the X with different Wq,Wv,Wk. I am assuming this is wrong? Like the same Q,K and V are projected down for different attention heads right? If so, Whats exactly wrong in my approach?

Comment: And you said int he subsequent layers, We use the previous layers output instead of input embeddings. The subsequent layers also require a Wq,Wv and Wk matrix which should be initialised right?

Comment: Yes, each attention layer has their own W matrices

Comment: When you say "Whats exactly wrong in my approach?", what approach are you referring to?

Comment: If so, All this while what I assumed was, for the first attention layer, We multiply the input X with Wq,Wv,Wk to obtain the first set of Q,K and V and for different heads within the same layer, We multiply the X with different Wq,Wv,Wk.

Comment: Yes, the inputs are multiplied by different $W_q$, $W_v$ and $W_k$, one for each head. Note that if we have self-attention (i.e. transformer encoder), the input X is the same, but in encoder-decoder attention the inputs are different.